# Using MACROS in Zabbix

Tags: macros, monitoring, zabbix

I have a big problem with MACROS in Zabbix. I want to define some MACROS in a host like {$IP1}, {$IP2} and so on. I wonder to know Why I cannot use them in the following areas:
Application name, Graph name, Item key.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These are called user macros (or variables) in Zabbix. The areas you listed regarding them:

- application name - not supported
- graph name - not supported
- item key - not supported in the item key itself, but supported in the item key parameters like `key[{$IP1}]`

If the question is why it's not supported - well, either because there has been limited interest, or because there are technical difficulties in supporting them.

See the [manual on usermacros](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location).

The questions sounds a bit like you might want the [low level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) instead - since 3.0 it also supports dynamic application names.

Comment: Thanks Dear @Richlv. Honestly I want to monitor netflow data of an ESXi which contains 10 VMs within Zabbix. The only way I know to add the ESxi and its VMs easily is that create a host with the name of ESXi's name, Application names as VMs's names and items will be define inside each Application. I need to define some user MACROS because of simplicity and rapid change in the IPs and names of VMs. But as you described it seems I cannot use MACORS in application name. Do you have any other way to implement such structure?

Comment: You might have to look into LLD, but that's a very different topic from your initial question.

Comment: But LLD supports only a limit range of items!! I want to monitor NetFlow data.I don't know whether I can use LLD or not. I want to add a rule for adding a new item like this for instance: netflow-ICMP_{$IPADDRESS2} with the key GetNetFlowProto[[{$IPADDRESS2}],icmp]. Can I add something like this by using LLD?

Comment: You should try not to mix several topics in the same question. I would suggest formulating the question as clearly as you can and asking a new question.

Comment: You are right @Richlv. Thank you. I would open a new question for the new issue.